# oruga ui next with theme bulma (closing modal)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

how to close the modal by clicking the card header icon? im doing a nuxt 3 project using oruga next theme bulma

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const privacy = ref(false)
</script>
<template>
  <o-modal v-model:active="privacy" canCancel="['escape', 'outside', 'button']" class="is-flex is-justify-content-center"
        scroll="clip">
        <div class="card">
            <header class="card-header">
                <p class="card-header-title">
                    Card header
                </p>
                <o-button class="card-header-icon" icon-left="close" size="medium" @click="">
                </o-button>
            </header>
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="content">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </o-modal>

    <o-button variant="ghost" @click="privacy = true">Privacy Policy</o-button>
</template>
```

i have tried with @click="privacy = false" and @click="privacy = !privacy" but not working

Comment: try `@click="() => privacy = false"`